# KeyDown for enter key does not work in textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, enter

First of all I am very sorry to open a duplicate question but the solutions which have been provided here do not work in my program. So I had to ask my problem as a new question. I have a program in C# for windows desktop and I want to execute a button when user press enter key in the textbox. I already found below code and some others. I don't know why but non of them works for me.

```
private void textbox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        buttonSearch.PerformClick();
    }

 }
```

I set KeyPreview to True and AcceptButton to None.  Keydown value to Textbox1_Keydown in Textbox Events. Is there any other setting I should apply ? When I set Acceptbutton to the command that I want to execute, it works fine. But problem is there are multiple textboxes in my program and each textbox will execute different commands. Please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: Does your Form handle a KeyDown event for which it sets `e.Handled = true`? If so, with `KeyPreview=true` set that will prevent this event from firing.

Comment: Do you specifically need KeyDown? Because another approach would be to use "TextChanged".

Comment: @steve16351 yes, my form have KeyDown event and as per your warning I set Keypreview to none. Beside that I also set AccepButton to none again and now it is working. Many thanks for your great help.